# Blocks that control other areas?

Tags: 7, blocks, ajax

I'm looking at migrating a site to Drupal. This site is an interactive site where selector controls in two side bars control the content in the main content area. So there's flash games in the main area, and there is a main 'menu' on the left sidebar, which controls which game is in the main area, and then there's a 'control panel' on the top bar which has some additional select boxes which also change the main content. All these changes happen through AJAX calls.

What module(s) should I use to re-create this functionality? I was thinking of making the controllers blocks, and the games pieces of content. So what should I use to have a block control the display a piece of content? Something that implements standard AJAX calls?

Comment: Woah, why the downvotes? The FAQ says "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". What have I done wrong here?

Comment: I have no clue. @downvoters: When you downvote a question, please specify why in a comment.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote because i like you

Comment: @glumbo you're a sweetheart :)

Comment: Don't worry too much about downvotes ... You get used to it ... Checkout my profile for similar samples ... FYI: I just upvoted it ... Also: any news/progress on how you resolved this issue?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I never wound up migrating the site to Drupal :þ